# Authorization Azure AD B2C

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2b

How does one achieve authorization for an api using Azure B2C?

---

##### Authentication

The setup in Azure AD b2c:
web: login
api: GetStuff

> web->sign-in>azure userflow:signinpolicy -(success)-> token = AccessTokenForUser("scope1","scope2"..)
> call [Authorize(Policy = "scope1")]api.GetStuff with requestheader=token.

Works great but this is only Authentication and how does one implement Authorization?

The a basic supported scenario should be:

If I belong to an item I should be able to edit it, i.e. write otherwise I should only have read.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below sample documents and it will help how to implement RBAC in B2C using Security Group. Using below sample you can consider attaching the roles to the user object as custom claim.

Reference: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac